# The first step "on becoming" or "to becoming" an employee

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Do you say:

> The first step on becoming a permanent employee ...

or

> The first step to becoming a permanent employee ...

Comment: They both are correct, and they both mean something. But they don't mean the same thing. The first step **on** becoming X is the first thing you do **after** you become X. The first step **to** becoming X is the first thing you do **in order to** become X (i.e, before, not afterwards).

Comment: *On* seems wrong (unless you mean "the first thing you do after"). *To* is acceptable, and so is *in*.

Comment: @JeffSahol Not necessarily! It depends what he is trying to say - see JohnLawler's answer.

Comment: @John, "on becoming" seems to require a preceding verb in my head (not sure why): "The first step to take on becoming…" is fine for me, but "The first step on becoming…" jars. Is that just me?

Comment: @TrevorD That's right, didn't think of that. I'd normally say *upon* becoming in that case, by the way.

Comment: _On becoming a PhD, he threw his mortarboard into the air_. Possibly _upon_ works better than _on_ here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's just you! What's wrong with "The first step on becoming a permanent employee is to find out where the tea room is."?

Comment: I don’t know—but it jars on my ears for some reason. I would say, “The first thing to do on becoming a permanent employee”.

Comment: Simpler questions can be asked on English Language Learners Q&A at ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

They mean different things.

```
The first step on becoming an employee
```

This is the first step AFTER you have become an employee.

```
The first step to becoming an employee
```

This is the first thing you have to do TO GET yourself to the point of being an employee.

The first step to becoming married is to find a nice girl. The first step on becoming married it to give her a big kiss at the front of a church full of friends and family.

(The above applies to heterosexual males of a religious persuasion, modify as you see fit...)

Comment: You are right. However,  on ELU, one is expected to know that much already.